# How can I resolve dependencies in nested application binary in Go project?

Tags: go, dependency-management, go-modules

This sounds stupid, but I am trying for build my new golang project for a while now and I am stuck with following error

> can't load package: package github.com/kuskmen/yamq/cmd/yamq-client: found packages main (main.go) and yamqclient (yamq-client.go) in C:\projects\yamq\cmd\yamq-client

I know this should be straightforward to fix, but I come from .NET and I am still not experienced in Go projects and its dependency resolution model hence the struggle.

My project structure looks like so

```
/yamq
    /cmd
        /yamq-client          // yamq client application binary
            main.go           // package main
            yamq-client.go    // package yamqclient
        /yamq-server          // yamq server application binary
            main.go           // package main
            yamq-server.go    // package yamqserver
    go.mod                // contains only "module github.com/kuskmen/yamq" for now
    ... // some library files that will probably be moved to /shared folder
```

so far so good, when I do `go build` in outermost directory ( /yamq ) it is building successfully (or at least it is not showing any errors), but when I try to build either `yamq-client` or `yamq-server` binaries I get the aforementioned error and every time I try to google it or find something useful I got some old article or answer that dates back 2013-2016 that suggests something about `$GOPATH` and etc which shouldn't be the case here since I am trying to use go modules.

Help a fellow .NET developer join Go community by explaining him how exactly modules work cause I found [this](https://github.com/go-modules-by-example/index/blob/master/009_submodules/README.md) and [this](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) useless or at least I am missing the point, thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you import yamq-client from its main.go?

Comment: I tried with import “yamqclient” and import “github.com/kuskmen/yamq-client” both gave the same error :/

Comment: The path should reflect your file system path. Move it out of `cmd` - no reason for that, and then you'll have `github.com/kuskmen/yamq/yamqclient`. Also rename `yamq-client` to `yamqclient` for consistency. In general, start with a single lib structure from one of the tutorials and make it work before you hop to two separate mains

Comment: the hard rule is - any files within the same directory *must* have consistent package names. So if building a executable - all files in that directory begin with `package main`. For a package - all files in a pkg directory begin with `package mypkgname`. The error you are seeing is warning that you have a mix of `main` and `yamqclient` package names in that particular build directory.

Comment: @EliBendersky I am following Go project template guidelines thats why I put my application binaries in cmd folder just like other projects (kubernetes, heroku etc)

Comment: @colminator thanks, I did not see anywhere this being written as a simple rule like you've told me, now it works as expected I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up from my comment above:

From https://golang.org/doc/code.html:

> - Go programmers typically keep all their Go code in a single workspace.
> - A workspace contains many version control repositories (managed by Git, for example).
> - Each repository contains one or more packages.
> - Each package consists of one or more Go source files in a ***single directory***.
> - The path to a package's directory determines its import path.

Answer (score 1):

For your project, I'd do something like this:

```
$ tree
.
├── clientlib
│   └── lib.go
├── cmd
│   ├── client
│   │   └── main.go
│   └── server
│       └── main.go
├── go.mod
└── serverlib
    └── lib.go

5 directories, 5 files

$ cat go.mod
module myproject.com
```

The module name is arbitrary (could be `github.com/yourname/yourproject`).

For the server side:

```
$ cat serverlib/lib.go 
package serverlib

import "fmt"

func Hello() {
    fmt.Println("Hello from serverlib.Hello")
}

$ cat cmd/server/main.go 
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "myproject.com/serverlib"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Running server")
    serverlib.Hello()
}
```

And now we can build and run it:

```
$ go build -o server cmd/server/main.go 
$ ./server
Running server
Hello from serverlib.Hello
```

The client side looks symmetrical.

Variations: you could name the `.go` files in `cmd/...` by their actual binary names - like `server.go` and `client.go`. The package in each is still `main`, but then `go build` creates an executable with the file's name (sans the `.go`) without needing to `-o` explicitly.